# Cases syntax when expression sought is a Quantity

Tags: date-and-time, units

From the following list I wish to extract those cases for which the magnitude of a quantity is greater than zero for which I would like to then create a DateListPlot.

```
 list = {{DateObject[{2017, 01}, "Month"], Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]},
         {DateObject[{2017, 02}, "Month"], Quantity[681.00, "Dollars"]},
         {DateObject[{2017, 03}, "Month"], Quantity[681.00, "Dollars"]},
         {DateObject[{2017, 04}, "Month"], Quantity[704.00, "Dollars"]},
         {DateObject[{2017, 05}, "Month"], Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]},
         {DateObject[{2017, 06}, "Month"], Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]},
         {DateObject[{2017, 07}, "Month"], Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]},
         {DateObject[{2017, 08}, "Month"], Quantity[704.00, "Dollars"]},
         {DateObject[{2017, 09}, "Month"], Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]},
         {DateObject[{2017, 10}, "Month"], Quantity[970.80, "Dollars"]},
         {DateObject[{2017, 11}, "Month"], Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]},
         {DateObject[{2017, 12}, "Month"], Quantity[704.00, "Dollars"]}}
```

However, using the following expression and variations I can't seem to create an appropriate syntax.  Instead creating a DateListPlot for a sublist with those elements for which the QuantityMagnitude is greater than zero, I get the error: "Quantity::unkunit: Unable to interpret unit specification {Automatic,Automatic}".

```
 DateListPlot[Cases[list, {_, x_} && QuantityMagnitude[x] > 0]]
```

The following doesn't work either:

```
 DateListPlot[Cases[list, {_, QuantityMagnitude[x_] > 0}]]
```

How can I structure the pattern for cases to obtain the desired result to include only non-zero values of the magnitude?

Comment: @creidhne - `QuantityMagnitude[x] > 0` does not require `x` to be a `Quantity`. A positive scalar would also evaluate to `True`

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

list = {{DateObject[{2017, 01}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]}, {DateObject[{2017, 02}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[681.00, "Dollars"]}, {DateObject[{2017, 03}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[681.00, "Dollars"]}, {DateObject[{2017, 04}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[704.00, "Dollars"]}, {DateObject[{2017, 05}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]}, {DateObject[{2017, 06}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]}, {DateObject[{2017, 07}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]}, {DateObject[{2017, 08}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[704.00, "Dollars"]}, {DateObject[{2017, 09}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]}, {DateObject[{2017, 10}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[970.80, "Dollars"]}, {DateObject[{2017, 11}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[0.00, "Dollars"]}, {DateObject[{2017, 12}, "Month"], 
    Quantity[704.00, "Dollars"]}};

list2 = Cases[list, {_, _Quantity?(QuantityMagnitude[#] > 0 &)}, 
   Infinity];

DateListPlot[list2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
  DateListPlot[
    list /. {_, _[_?NonPositive, _]} :> Nothing,
    PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
listnew = Cases[list, {_, Quantity[_?Positive, _]}]
```

or

```
listnew = Cases[list, {_, Quantity[_?(# > 0 &), _]}]
DateListPlot[listnew, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: All approaches informative for handling lists containing explicitly specified quanties.  DateListPlot[list /. {_, _[_?NonPositive, _]} :> Nothing, 
 PlotRange -> All], however, plots missing values as gaps in the data.  The rest exclude missing values.  Thanks for the insight gentlemen.